# $ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I have installed NPM. I install it to `C:\Users\Irfan\AppData\Roaming\npm`
Now, how to create my app

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

When I run the command on command prompt there is error about $ as it isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be including the $ on the command you run. It is there only to say that the rest of line is executed on command line. so try to run

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

on command prompt.

Also, first you need to actually install Cordova with

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: C:\Users\Irfan\AppData\Roaming\npm after this line execute that comand you gave me?

Comment: Check the update I made, so 1. install NPM, 2. install Cordova and 3. create your project. You also are gonna need the appropriate SDKs if you don't intend to use [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/).

Comment: hey its runing thanx but there is an c:\program files\irfan\hello shell.js internal error Error : EPREM operation not permitted 'c:\program files\irfan\hello'

Comment: I do not think you have the permission to write under `program files`. Try somewhere under your user name such as C:\Users\Irfan\Documents\

Comment: ohh that's greate supperb 1 think cordova platform add andriod there is an error node is not recongnized internal and external command operation prgram or batch file.

Comment: That is worth separate ticket, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68521/discussion-between-irfan-and-sanfor).